# Unable to select first value from dropdown in jquery

Tags: magento2, jquery, dropdown-attribute, drop-downs

I populated the dropdown with the help of array. for example I have array with elements (ali,abid,naqvi).

Problem.....

when I clear the cache and reload the page. and first time I am unable to select first value which is "ali". but if after cache clear and page reload, I select "abid" or "naqvi" first time and then select "ali" it work fine.

in short...after page reload I cann't select first value of dropdown unless I select other values first.

Comment: Sharing your code would be better than explaining. please share

Comment: yeah you are right bro. but I got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually problem was that I was using "onchange" function.
When I used "onclick" it was working fine and also select the first value from drop too.like I was using

$('.pro_size').on('change', function(event){

after modification

$('.pro_size').on('click', function(event){     =>worked fine